# Specific issue with iteration in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

So I have posed this question to multiple people, none of whom have been able to solve the problem. My website Program in Person (http://www.programinperson.com) is up and running fine; however, when I look at one user in particular, there seems to be an error which appears. If I look at it while I am logged in, the error appears. If I am a "guest" and not logged in, then it does not appear - This is because of an if statement I have in my code. The main line is question is the block I have on the 4th line (.nearby is there due to the geocoder gem). Again, it works for all the other users except this one.

I have placed the code in question, with the error logs and success logs into a gist: https://gist.github.com/Jdayvie/c4043079ca84af438d6a

Please let me know if you have any ideas, thoughts or questions!

Thank you,

Joe

Comment: Did you try to print out this user nearbys in rails console? Check what it returns for this particular user.

Comment: Let me give it a try right now.

Comment: irb(main):013:0> a.nearbys(50)
=> nil | Nothing returns, unless that is incorrect?

Comment: That's the problem. You cannot iterate nil.

Comment: That makes sense; however, users before and after him have signed up without an issue and everything is fine. How come this one user has this issue and how do I ensure it does not happen again? It's difficult to understand when I don't know how it happened =(

Comment: Check all properties of this user in rails console. Maybe there is a hidden nil somewhere.

Comment: Hmm...well, thank you. It seems that the users' Longitude and Latitude are nil. I do not understand how that is possible since the geocoder gem is used...

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow - you are **STRONGLY ENCOURAGED** to add any pertinent code, logs entries etc in the body of the question. Your question should be as self contained as possible. This safeguards against link rot and poor quality content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we figured out - some of this user's properties are set to nil (latitude and longitude in this case), so user.nearbys returns nil too. And you cannot iterare nils. You have to reassign this two properties and it should work.